# CoreAnimation warning, deleted thread with uncommitted CATransaction

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, core-animation, catransition

sometimes I have a following warnings in my app and then app freezes and stops working.
I don't know why does this happen. Does anyone can help me?

```
> <Warning>: CoreAnimation: warning, deleted thread with uncommitted CATransaction; created by:
0   QuartzCore                          0x32f303b3 <redacted> + 266
1   QuartzCore                          0x32f30269 <redacted> + 224
2   QuartzCore                          0x32f308c7 <redacted> + 30
3   QuartzCore                          0x32f33bf3 <redacted> + 182
4   QuartzCore                          0x32f8b985 <redacted> + 36
5   UIKit                               0x3383ec57 <redacted> + 30
6   UIKit                               0x334eca33 <redacted> + 114
7   UIKit                               0x33413aab <redacted> + 246
8   UIKit                               0x3383a6a1 <redacted> + 160
9   Program_TV_Pro                      0x00017b3b -[MainMenuViewController grabURLInBackgroundForEntryFromAppDelegate] + 1166
10  Program_TV_Pro                      0x000180a3 __49-[MainMenuViewController contextChannelsChanged:]_block_invoke + 138
11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x3b800d1b <redacted> + 10
12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x3b807d71 <redacted> + 220
13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x3b807f59 <redacted> + 56
14  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x3b942dbf _pthread_wqthread + 298
15  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x3b942c84 start_wqthread + 8
```

and warning at another time:

```
CoreAnimation: warning, deleted thread with uncommitted CATransaction; created by:
0   QuartzCore                          0x32f303b3 <redacted> + 266
1   QuartzCore                          0x32f30269 <redacted> + 224
2   QuartzCore                          0x32f31871 <redacted> + 24
3   QuartzCore                          0x32f3207f <redacted> + 130
4   UIKit                               0x3338a3d7 <redacted> + 1562
5   Program_TV_Pro                      0x00115c2b -[ReplaysTableViewController downloadReplays] + 346
6   Program_TV_Pro                      0x00113cbb __41-[ReplaysTableViewController viewDidLoad]_block_invoke52 + 46
7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x3b800d1b <redacted> + 10
8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x3b807d71 <redacted> + 220
9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x3b807f59 <redacted> + 56
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x3b942dbf _pthread_wqthread + 298
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x3b942c84 start_wqthread + 8
```

Comment: I think the operation you perform, probably some download, has already finished in background thread, but the animation triggered on same thread didn't. Try to use dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{}) for your animation.

Comment: Thanks for reply! Actually I do not have any animations in my UIView, but there are many views and a UIContainerView with UITableViewController. When I get a NSNotification from another class about downloading and saving finished, then I reload a UITableView data in UIContainerView.

Comment: Not sure then, are you reloading on main thread? Are you using [tableview beginUpdates/endUpdates]?